# How to Make Header Stick on Scroll Without JQuery in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make my nav at the top of the page a sticky header and am looking for a node module equivalent to React Native's ScrollView wrapper but for ReactJS. So far, the only thing that seemed useful was [react-sticky,](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky) but it is no longer being maintained and doesn't seem to work with React 16. I do not want to use JQuery for this, unless of course, this is somehow considered best practice in ReactJS.

Comment: The better solution is CSS's `position: sticky;` You can learn it from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning

Comment: Ahhhh THANK YOU! I had never heard of the sticky prop before. Right under my nose the whole time.

Comment: FYI It doesnot have support for IE<=11.

Comment: @stack26 `position: sticky` is available in EDGE 16+, so don't worry (it's just a nice feature, not a must-have).

Comment: `position: fixed` with a z-index of 10000 works everywhere https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [React Headroom](https://kyleamathews.github.io/react-headroom/) if you want to to show/hide navigation based on scroll. If you want your Header to always be at the top, then just use CSS -`position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;`